# Access VBA Criteria of AND and &

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am running the following query in Access VBA

```
    Case "Customer Name"
        strSQL = "SELECT CustomerID, Customer_Name, Industry FROM TBLCUSTOMERSNEW WHERE ucase(Customer_Name) Like '*" & UCase(tempStr) & "*'" & " ORDER BY Customer_Name"
        Me.lstSearchResults.ColumnCount = 4
        Me.lstSearchResults.ColumnWidths = "1cm;7cm;12cm;"
```

Is it possible to amend this query so that when the value being searched for (`tempStr`) contains a "&" the records returned also contain records where `customer_name` contains "and", and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that's possible with a simple `If` statement. Please share the code calling the query as well, and share it in the format it is in VBA (with surrounding quotes and such). (You just want to match _John & Jack_ to _John and Jack_, as I understand it?)

Comment: Short answer yes - you would have to use Instr to find the & or And and create a second like statement with the additional search, then add it as an OR to your Where clause.  Two things - Access is not case sensitive by default so you don't need the UCase, and using * at the beginning of the search will mean indexes on the searched field can't be used, if this is a large recordset it will get very slow.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - "John & Jack to John and Jack" - that's right, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought up a simple alternative not using any `IF` logic for you.

```
SELECT   customerid, 
         customer_name, 
         industry 
FROM     tblcustomersnew 
WHERE    Replace(Ucase(customer_name), "&", "AND") LIKE '*" & Replace(UCase(tempStr), "&", "AND") & "*'" & " 
ORDER BY customer_name
```

That should do it.

Comment: When adding this as VBA (strSQL = "SELECT customerid, customer_name, industry FROM tblcustomersnew WHERE Replace(Ucase(customer_name), " & ", " And ") LIKE '*" & Replace(UCase(tempStr), "&", "AND") & "*'" & " ORDER BY customer_name"), I'm getting a Type Mismatch error on that line of code.

Comment: You do need to double up those quotes if you're using it in VBA, that's why I asked for the VBA code. So this: `Replace(Ucase(customer_name), " & ", " And ") ` becomes `Replace(Ucase(customer_name), "" & "", "" And "") `. Do this only for the first one.